# CRM 2011 jQuery from external site - permissions?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937117/access-ms-crm-web-services-from-external-app-javascript) post about accessing CRM data from an external application. How do we handle permissions? In my case, an external web site will be pushing & pulling data from CRM 2011 in the cloud. How will permissions be handled? How do I set permissions when making a call? Every piece of documentation I've seen shows examples of jQuery, but running within CRM, rather than externally.

Comment: I've cut small pieces of code from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx) article, just to create an AccountSet record. I browsed the OrganizationData.svc endpoint, authenticated, then ran my HTML page which executes the jQuery. I get a "success" result on the ajax post result, but data is empty. Is it connecting, but not submitting the data?

Comment: Using fiddler, i see the request getting a 302 (redirect) when it hits OrganizationData.svc, and it stops there. When I browse it manually, I end up with a 200, cause it worked fine. I'm guessing the redirect is Microsoft's redirection for authentication. But why does it vary in browser vs jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but according to the SDK you cannot use the REST-endpoint outside of the CRM.

The article about [Use the REST Endpoint for Web Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx) states following limitation

> Authentication is only possible within the application
>   Use of the REST endpoint is limited to JScript libraries or SilverlightWeb resources.

This explains why all examples only show the internal usage.

Comment: Argh...Thanks for that. What alternatives do I have? I need to be and to send and receive data with CRM externally.

Comment: @Tim Gabrhel which technology do you use?

Comment: The external web app that will be consuming this data is a php based application. I have to find some sort of way to get a 'hook' in to CRM to pass the data back and forth. However, I don't think my question is still applicable. It's more of a 'where will this *thing* live' question, and that will determine my answer.